# Routing Error when using Wicked Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Ryan Bate's tutorial and am getting a routing error.  I'm super new at this all, so I'm sure it's something obvious.

My listing steps controller is this

```
class ListingStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard

steps :building, :space, :ownership, :terms

def show
    @property = Property.new(params[:building])
    render_wizard
end


def update
    @property = Property.new(params[:building])
    render_wizard @property
end
```

end

and my building.html.erb file is this

```
    <%= form_for @property, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

<h1> Tell us about your building </h1>
    <div class="form">
      <%= f.label :company %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :company, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>


    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

And my routes file is this

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :spaces
  resources :properties
  resources :listing_steps

  devise_for :users
  root 'properties#index'
  get 'list' => "pages#list"
  get 'reserve' => "pages#reserve"
end
```

here is my terminal readout:

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/listing_steps/building"):
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /Users/zak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/zak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/zak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (58.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (32.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (80.4ms)
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

properties_controller.rb

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    if @property.save
      session[:property_id] = @property.id
      redirect_to listing_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: doesn't look like it.  I still get this:

No route matches [POST] "/listing_steps/building"